# Python 3: Grouping a list of dict by a tuple of fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, grouping

I need to group a list of dict by a tuple of fields and write a function, which will do this for different sets of data.

For example:
a list of dict:

```
[{'bnf_code': '0101010G0AAABAB',
 'items': 2,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'bnf_name': 'Co-Magaldrox_Susp 195mg/220mg/5ml S/F',
  'nic': 5.98,
  'act_cost': 5.56,
  'quantity': 1000},
 {'bnf_code': '0101021B0AAAHAH',
  'items': 1,
  'practice': 'N81013',
  'bnf_name': 'Alginate_Raft-Forming Oral Susp S/F',
  'nic': 1.95,
  'act_cost': 1.82,
  'quantity': 500}]
```

and I want to groupby a tuple -> `('bnf_name', 'post_code'))`.

I can't use pandas.

I've tried with below code but it raises a KeyError.

```
def group_by_field(data,fields):
    groups = {name: [] for name in fields}
    for script in data:
        for name in fields:
            groups[script[name]].append(script)
    return groups
```

Comment: What do you mean groupby a tuple? Can you show us the expected output? Also provide a big enough input to have a  meaningful output?

Comment: Have a look at [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: the `post_code` field don't exist. What do you expect should happen then?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that does what you describe:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group_by_field(data, fields):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for d in data:
        key = tuple(d[f] for f in fields)
        res[key].append(d)
    return dict(res)
```

Comment: FWIW if you have at least two fields `attrgetter(*fields)` returns a function which retrieves and tuple-ifies the values from a mapping (sadly it's irregular: if a single key is provided it returns the value directly, not wraped in a tuple).

Comment: While this is a nice abstraction, you would *probably* want to add special handling for missing fields, so I wouldn't recommend it in this case.

Comment: TFA says nothing about potentially missing field, and your implementation has no provision for them, so I fail to see how relevant they are.